# How to read xlsx file using POI?

Tags: java, excel, groovy, apache-poi, xlsx

I read the xls file using POI HSSF, everything was correct. But I didn't learn how to read the input file xlsx. Previously, I did not work with xlsx, I read the material on the network on different resources, I did not notice the difference except for replacing HSSF with XSSF and connecting additional. libraries. However, it throws an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.newDocumentBuilder () Ljavax / xml /
> parsers / DocumentBuilder;

Swears at

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook (p_file);
def res = SSC.execute (connection, file, "test.xlsx")
```

The code is given below (I will be very grateful if anyone can help in solving the problem now / on ";" do not pay attention, because I use groovy, the rest is similar to java):

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell

import javax.xml.soap.Text
import java.sql.Blob
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook; //New imports to read XLSX format
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet; //New imports to read XLSX format
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.util.Iterator;


import java.io.*;

class XM_PARSE_XLS {

    def execute(Connection conn, InputStream p_file, String p_filename) {



        Sql sql = new Sql(conn)

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(p_file);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrAllData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        String strsql
        Integer cntStr = 0
        HashSet rw_okpo = new HashSet();

        // идем по листам в файле
        wb.each { XSSFSheet myExcelSheet ->
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(Locale.ROOT);

            // идем по страницам файла
            myExcelSheet.each{  Row myrow ->

                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

                if (cntStr >= 0) {
                    // идем по строкам с данными
                    Integer numCell = 0;
                    String typ = '';

                    myrow.each { Cell mycell ->
                        String value = ""; // приводит любые ячейки к строковому формату

                        // если тип Строка
                        if (mycell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            value = mycell.getStringCellValue();
                            typ = 'S'
                            // если тип число
                        }  else {
                            // а для числовых ячеек или ячеек даты значение будет отформатировано на основе правил форматирования / стиля, примененных к ячейке, а затем возвращено как строка
                            value = formatter.formatCellValue(mycell);
                            value = value.replace(',','');
                            typ = 'N'
                            if (cntStr >= 0){
                            switch(numCell) { //0-17
                                case 0:
                                    hm.put("t0", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    hm.put("t1", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    hm.put("t2", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    hm.put("t3", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    hm.put("t4", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    hm.put("t5", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 6:
                                    hm.put("t6", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 7:
                                    hm.put("t7", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 8:
                                    hm.put("t8", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 9:
                                    hm.put("t9", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 10:
                                    hm.put("t10", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 11:
                                    hm.put("t11", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 12:
                                    hm.put("t12", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 13:
                                    hm.put("t13", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 14:
                                    hm.put("t14", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 15:
                                    hm.put("t15", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 16:
                                    hm.put("t16", value + ";");
                                    break;
                                case 17:
                                    hm.put("t17", value + "\r\n");
                                    break;
                            }
                            numCell = numCell + 1;

                        }

                    }
                }
                if(hm) arrAllData.add(hm);
                cntStr = cntStr + 1;
            }
        }



        return res;
    }
    static void main(String... args) {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
        //Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.193.21.75:3333/OLAP2", "LAS", "ASfDER7F4FA")
        connection.setAutoCommit(true)

        try {

            def file = new File("test.xlsx").newInputStream()
            def SSC = new XM_PARSE_XLS()
            def res = SSC.execute(connection,file,"test.xlsx")

        } finally {
            connection.close()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

A `NoSuchMethodError` on run time occurs if the code runs using another library version than it was compiled with.

Here the code probably was compiled using `apache poi 4.1.2` but on run time there is a lower version of `apache poi` used.

The method `public static DocumentBuilder newDocumentBuilder()` was introduced in `org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper` in `apache poi 4.1.2`. It is not present in lower versions.

Also make sure you are not mixing different `apache poi` versions. That is not supported and also might lead to such errors because different versions exporting different versions of methods too. See [faq-N10204](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204).

Maybe lower versions of `apache poi` classes are shipped from other libraries too. You can ask the `ClassLoader` where a special class (`org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper` in your case) came from on run time:

```
...
ClassLoader classloader = org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.class.getClassLoader();
java.net.URL res = classloader.getResource("org/apache/poi/util/XMLHelper.class");
String path = res.getPath();
System.out.println("XMLHelper came from " + path);
...
```

If that is not the `jar` you expect, you get at least an idea which other library ships that class too.

Comment: Here's what's in the project structure:
https://ibb.co/vPm3qLM
Going to remove POI version 3? Or add something else?

Comment: Yes, removing all versions apart of `4.1.2`. mixing different `apache poi`versions is not supported.

Comment: Removed the lower version and left only 4.1.2, but the bug persisted. What do you advise?
https://ibb.co/7g82MtJ
https://ibb.co/k2hj7Qq

Comment: Maybe a lower version of `org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper` class is shipped from another library. See supplement in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I did it, but the errors don't stop. Wasn't it enough to just change HSSF to XSSF?
https://ibb.co/TKF1PvB
68: if (mycell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
44:  myrow.each { Cell mycell ->
55:  myExcelSheet.each{  Row myrow ->
51:  wb.each { XSSFSheet myExcelSheet ->
362:  def res = SSC.execute(connection,file,"test.xlsx")

Comment: This is another issue now which has nothing to do with this question. In current `apache poi` versions `Cell.getCellType` returns a `CellType`. So it would must be `if (mycell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING)`.

Comment: "Wasn't it enough to just change HSSF to XSSF? ": No, as a programmer you always need full knowledge about the libraries you are using. Refer https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html and https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Can I ask you for any contact? Mail, messenger, social network?